# If we define for set $S,T$ that $ |S|-|T|=|S-T|$, is this well-defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

#### Problem

If we define for set $S,T$ that $|S|-|T|=|S\setminus T|$, then this is well-defined in the sense that for all sets
$S,T,S',T'$, if $|S|=|S'|$ and $|T|=|T'|$, then $|S|-|T| =|S'|\setminus |T'|$.

#### My solution

False. By definition: $|S|-|T|=|S\setminus T|$   and $S\setminus T=\{x\in S|x\notin T\}$.
If $|S|=|S'|$   and $|T|=|T'|$, then $|S|-|T | =|S'|-|T'|$.

Let $S=\{1\}$, $S'=\{1\}$, $T=\{1\}$, $T'=\{2\}$. Then $|S|=1=|S'|$  and $|T|=1=|T'|$.
Also,
$$|S|-|T|=|S-T|   = |\{1\}-\{1\}|   = |\emptyset|   = 0 $$
and $$ |S'|-|T'|=|S'|-|T'|   = |\{1\}-\{2\}|   = |\{1\}|  = 1$$
This proves that $|S|-|T |$ and $|S'|-|T'|$  are not always equal.

Can you please give feedback on my answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: I reformatted the post. See [help on notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. The cardinality of the difference of two sets cannot be determined from the cardinalities of sets themselves. This does not work for unions or intersections, either. (But it does work for products, and powers.)